# View not moving up for custom keyboard height - swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I have looked around stackoverflow and I have been unsuccessful to find a fix to this issue. I have added code to shift my view up as per the height of the keyboard. This works perfectly for iOS default keyboard, however, this does not work for custom keyboards. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class AddCategoryViewController: UIViewController {

var partialView: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 150
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == partialView {
            let offset: CGSize = ((notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size)!

            if keyboardSize.height == offset.height {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
                })
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height - offset.height
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != partialView {
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: self.view.window)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: self.view.window)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0.2, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        let frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.partialView, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)

    }, completion: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AddCategoryViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AddCategoryViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
}
```

Hoping that you could help me fix this so that the view pushes up the height of the custom keyboard's height.

Comment: Try change `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey ` to `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`

Comment: @Tj3n - This didn't seem to work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

dont change the Frame of theView.. just change the translation of View

```
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0.2, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX : 0 , y : partialView)

}, completion: nil)
```

> And to Reset it just use

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
```

Comment: This doesn't work on non-system keyboards. Eg SwiftKey keyboard behaves weird on this.